# mysql utf8mb4 doesn't seem to recognize some emojis like 

Tags: mysql, unicode, emoji, utf8mb4

[image]

You can see that 'bio' column is set to UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

But when I put  <- these two into 'bio' column, it's somehow saved as ????...

There are some emojis which can be recognized and saved well such as ❌  .

Does utf8mb4 cover every emoji included in Unicode 8.0?

Comment: Even version 5.5.3 (_when using utf8mb4_) handles every emoji.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my table is not set as utf8mb4.

It seems like not only column encoding but also table encoding must be utf8mb4 too.

Comment: And the connection.